# Why make an iterator to be an iterable too? What is the use case for such organisation?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) currently. When going over the section ["Iterators of ES6"](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch3.md#custom-iterators), I came across the following piece of code

```
var Fib = {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        var n1 = 1, n2 = 1;

        return {
            // make the iterator an iterable
            [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; },

            next() {
                var current = n2;
                n2 = n1;
                n1 = n1 + current;
                return { value: current, done: false };
            },

            return(v) {
                console.log(
                    "Fibonacci sequence abandoned."
                );
                return { value: v, done: true };
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Here what is the purpose of making the iterator that is returned from the iterable Fib to be an iterable too ? In this [Medium article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-es6-iterables-iterators-4bdd0b084082) the author states that

> "Please note that this is the pattern followed by ES6 built-in
>   iterators."

for making iterators in turn iterables. I have not found an explanation to this pattern or even use cases by searching the MDN docs or simply in Google. Can some one please point me in the right direction to know about this ?

Comment: He explained the reason in the [medium](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-es6-iterables-iterators-4bdd0b084082) article itself, right? `Although for-of only works with iterables, not with iterators, being the same means that we can pause the execution of for-of and continue after words.`

Comment: The purpose of making an iterator iterable is to make it consumable by the `for-of` loop and `...`, the spread operator.